# adding instruction points to a route line using leaflet.js

Tags: javascript, leaflet

i use leaflet.js to show a route in my web project. I have mastered everything successfully, except that I cannot display instruction points on the route.

i used the following code to show the Route on the map:

```js
api.getRoute(routingLink).then(res =>{
    const routeLayer = L.geoJSON(res.data.features,{}).addTo(layerGroup) //shows route on the map 
})
```

my question is how can i add instruction points to the route that shows the instruction in popup on clicking it.

here a screenshot from the route that
shows the route between to places but not the instructions:

[image: Screenshoot]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem myself. I'll just leave the question online if it's interesting to someone other. and although solved as follows:

```js
api.getRoute(routingLink).then(res =>{
 
    var geojsonMarkerOptions = {//Options for circleMarker
        radius: 8,
        fillColor: "#ffffff",
        color: "#000",
        weight: 1,
        opacity: 1,
        fillOpacity: 0.8
     }

     const routeLayer = L.geoJSON(res.data.features,{
        onEachFeature(feature,layer){//the data from each feature in my situation it was a single feature, i used a route between only two places.
          const featureCoords = feature.geometry.coordinates[0]
          for(let step of feature.properties.legs[0].steps){//iterate throw all Steps 
             if(step.instruction){//if the step has instruction attribute, add a circleMarker
                let instructionPoint = L.circleMarker([featureCoords[step.from_index][1],featureCoords[step.from_index][0]], geojsonMarkerOptions).addTo(layerGroup)
                instructionPoint.addEventListener("click",e =>{// add eventListener that show a popup with the instraction.
                  L.popup().setLatLng([featureCoords[step.from_index][1],featureCoords[step.from_index][0]]).setContent(step.instruction.text).addTo(layerGroup)
                })
                             
             }
          }
        },
     }).addTo(layerGroup) //add the route to the layerGroup
```

Note: Iam using the api provided from https://apidocs.geoapify.com/playground/routing.

a screenshoot shows the route after the circleMarker with instructions added onto it

[image]

Comment: Never links to external image websites because they disappear after some time. Add here to stackoverflow, just move the photo above the textarea and leave it.